# Help needed in NonLinearModelFit

Tags: fitting

I am trying to fit my experimental data to a very complicated equation which contains digamma function. I tried to learn from various discussions about fitting but I could not quite figure out how to deal with it. Posted are my experimental data and function I want to fit with. I am a new Mathematica user. Can anyone help me?

```
data= {{37.6, 0}, {32.1, 1}, {25.6, 2}, {20.1, 3}, {15.2, 4}, {11.1,4.5}, {8.4, 5}, {5.6, 5.5}, {2.1, 6.5}, {0, 7.}}
```

Function I want to fit is rather bulky defined as follows,

```
eq=(0.564 + a) (Log[x/41] + PolyGamma[0.5 + p1] + 1.96351) + (0.564 - a)(Log[x/41] + PolyGamma[0.5 + p2] + 1.96351) + 0.44 (Log[x/41] + PolyGamma[0.5 + p1] + 1.96351) (Log[x/41] + PolyGamma[0.5 + p2] + 1.96351)== 0

a= (-3.11*^11 + 0.52 (1.97*^11 + 
  1.82*^15 y (1 - b)))/(2.25*^24 + (1.97*^11 + 1.82*^15 y (1 - b))^2)^0.5;
p1= (1/x)3.81*10^-12 (1.51*10^12 + (2.25*10^24 + (1.97*10^11 + 1.82*10^15 y (1 - b))^2)^0.5 + 1.82*10^15 y (1 + b));

P2=(1/x)3.81*10^-12 (1.51*10^12 - (2.25*10^24 + (1.97*10^11 + 1.82*10^15 y (1 - b))^2)^0.5 + 1.82*10^15 y (1 + b));
```

The fitting parameter is only 'b' and plot should be y vs x.

I tried this:

```
NonLinearModelFit[data,(0.564 + a) (Log[x/41] + PolyGamma[0.5 + p1] + 1.96351) + (0.564 - a)(Log[x/41] + PolyGamma[0.5 + p2] + 1.96351) + 0.44 (Log[x/41] + PolyGamma[0.5 + p1] + 1.96351) (Log[x/41] + PolyGamma[0.5 + p2] + 1.96351), {b},{x,y}]
```

Unfortunately, it gives nothing.

Comment: I think you have a couple of typos: you define `P2`, but then later use `p2` (lower case), and `NonlinearModelFit` has no capital "L".

Answer (score 1):

You have a data point `{0, y}` even though the formula contains `Log[x/41]`. I exclude that data point. Also you have used `P2` and `p2` interchangeably. I remove the `==` from `eq` because it should only be there when you want something to be exact equal (except for rounding error).

```
eq = (0.564 + a) (Log[x/41] + PolyGamma[0.5 + p1] + 1.96351) +
     (0.564 - a) (Log[x/41] + PolyGamma[0.5 + p2] + 1.96351) +
            0.44 (Log[x/41] + PolyGamma[0.5 + p1] + 1.96351)
                 (Log[x/41] + PolyGamma[0.5 + p2] + 1.96351);

a = (-3.11*^11 + 0.52 (1.97*^11 + 1.82*^15 y (1 - b)))/
     (2.25*^24 + (1.97*^11 + 1.82*^15 y (1 - b))^2)^0.5;
p1 = (1/x) 3.81*10^-12 (1.51*10^12 + (2.25*10^24 + (1.97*10^11 +
           1.82*10^15 y (1 - b))^2)^0.5 + 1.82*10^15 y (1 + b));
p2 = (1/x) 3.81*10^-12 (1.51*10^12 - (2.25*10^24 + (1.97*10^11 +
           1.82*10^15 y (1 - b))^2)^0.5 + 1.82*10^15 y (1 + b));

err[b_?NumericQ] = Total[Map[eq^2 /. {x -> #[[1]], y -> #[[2]]} &, data[[;; -2]]]];
```

`NonlinearModelFit` only works if you can solve the equation for `y`. I don't think it's possible so the function `err` computes sum of `eq` squares instead, which can be minimized with respect to `b` (you want `eq` to be close to 0). Looking at

```
ListPlot[Table[{b, err[b]}, {b, -2, 2, 1/10}]]
```

[image]

The minimum seems to be about `b==0`, so we get:

```
FindMinimum[err[b], {b, 0.00001, 0}]
```

> {428.80412, {b -> -0.000056068596}}